# Subversion error E155036 on a brand-new working copy

Tags: svn, upgrade

Bizarre behaviour from Subversion on Ubuntu 16.04 - I created a (file-based) repository, check out a working copy to another drive, tried to "svn add" a folder to the working copy... and got:

```
svn: E155036: The working copy at '/home/mike/dev/myproject_wc/Boost'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.9.7 (r1800392)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

But this had all been created new, all using the same version of SVN! (Initially 1.9.3, then I built and installed 1.9.7, but with the same result.)  I peeked into the SQLite database to see what version the working-copy was:

```
sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "PRAGMA user_version"
31
```

So the working copy WAS version 31!  Unsurprisingly, doing "svn upgrade" made no difference.

---

The answer was in the error-message, if only I'd read it more carefully - *the folder I was trying to add* already contained a ".svn" subfolder, which Nautilus wasn't displaying (lesson learned - if in doubt, "ls -la").  Once I deleted that subfolder, "svn add" worked as expected.  D'oh!

Comment: I have same problem, any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Check that the folder you're trying to add doesn't already contain SVN metadata, like a ".svn" subfolder (and note that Nautilus and other file-managers will usually not display files/folders whose names begin with ".", hence my comment about using `ls -la` to list the contents of the folder).